# 'ExecutionModelApplication' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) wp8 c#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

In my windows phone 8 application I want to preserve state of my application, using this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff967547%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

And seen in the topic of `Modifying the Page Class`

I modify my `MainPage` class constructor and add this line:

```
(Application.Current as ExecutionModelApplication.App).ApplicationDataObjectChanged +=
                          new EventHandler(MainPage_ApplicationDataObjectChanged);
```

To my `MainPage` class constructor like bwlow:

```
public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            // Sample code to localize the ApplicationBar
            //BuildLocalizedApplicationBar();
            _isNewPageInstance = true;

            // Set the event handler for when the application data object changes.
            (Application.Current as ExecutionModelApplication.App).ApplicationDataObjectChanged +=
                          new EventHandler(MainPage_ApplicationDataObjectChanged);
        }
```

But i getting error below at `ExecutionModelApplication` :

`The type or namespace name 'ExecutionModelApplication' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

How do I resolve it, Kindly suggest me.

Waiting for your reply.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

"ExecutionModelApplication" is the name of the application class in that example in your link.  You need to substitute it with the name of your own application class.

See:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/d5a8bf79-e968-4ff7-8b2d-384968d66a06/wher-is-executionmodelapplication-type-defined?forum=wpdevelop